# Has anyone used a DECODE table (set of tables) in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Has anyone ever used a series of tables togather called a DECODE?

This is where you have the following types of tables:

```
WORK_ORDER
==========
ID, 
WORK_ORDER_TYPE, 
CUSTOMER_TYPE

DECODE_TYPE
===========
ID, 
NAME, 
DESCRIPTION

DECODE
======
ID, 
NAME
```

I don't remember how exactly it is set up, but it is set up kind of like this.  The whole point is to eliminate adding additional tables for each type.

I am looking for a full description including instructions, or a blog posting out there somewhere that I can't seem to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be describing standard [lookup tables](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/) (fully described in linked article).

These would be tables whose primary key is referenced as foreign key from whatever table that is using them.

See the linked article for all the details you are asking for.